# Webscraping Amazon with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

I am trying to webscrape Amazon's reviews: [https://www.amazon.com/Python-Crash-Course-Hands-Project-Based/dp/1593276036/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1541450645&sr=8-3&keywords=python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593276036)

Here is my code:

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Kevin\'s_request'}
r = req.get('https://www.amazon.com/Python-Crash-Course-Hands-Project-Based/dp/1593276036/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1541450645&sr=8-3&keywords=python', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
soup.find(class_="a-expander-content a-expander-partial-collapse-content")
```

I only end up with an empty list. I am using Python 3.6.4 in Jupyter Notebooks and BS 4

Comment: When sending requests on my end to the URL I receive a 503 HTTP Status code. Check the status code on your side. If using the `requests` library you can do `r.status_code` where `r` is a `requests.get()`

Comment: I did that but left that part out earlier. I edited my questions to reflect that part. Everything seems to working fine but the .find_all(...) to get the text. It just returns an empty list. When I use the same code with another website it works.

Comment: The reviews are wrapped in another `div` called `a-section review`. See [here](https://imgur.com/a/VAcaakn). When trying `len(soup.findAll(class_='a-section review'))` the result is 8, which is how many reviews are displayed.

Comment: I see what you're saying but when I do `len(soup.findAll(class_='a-section review'))` I get a length of 0 I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: How are you initializing the `BeautifulSoup` class? With `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)`?

Comment: I initialized it with `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")` Should I remove the `"html.parser"`?

Comment: @KPH3802: please edit your question to post your full code that defines and initializes your `soup` object. Also, what versions of Python and BS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach. Turn out that your selector could not find anything. However, I've fixed it to serve the purpose:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_reviews(s,url):
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'
    response = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    return soup.find_all("div",{"data-hook":"review-collapsed"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    link = 'https://www.amazon.com/Python-Crash-Course-Hands-Project-Based/dp/1593276036/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1541450645&sr=8-3&keywords=python'    
    with requests.Session() as s:
        for review in get_reviews(s,link):
            print(f'{review.text}\n')
```

Comment: With this syntax I assume there is only the one _get_ and as you loop here _for review in get_reviews(s,link)_ you are re-using the returned object ? I am not familiar enough wih this library and syntax yet to understand the efficiency I assume is here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's happening on your side, but this code works fine. 
Here it goes (python 3.6, BSP 4.6.3):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def s_comments(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Bob\'s_request'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers )
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise ConnectionError

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    return soup.find_all(class_="a-expander-content a-expander-partial- collapse-content")


url = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/1593276036'    
reviews = s_comments(url)
for i, review in enumerate(reviews):
    print('---- {} ----'.format(i))
    print(review.text)
```

Comment: When I use this code I still get an empty list. Could it be something on my end?

Comment: Yes. Try to print the response you are getting back like:

Comment: print(response.content) and also your parsed object. like soup.prettify()